# How to create a movable panel in wx python

Tags: wxpython, movable

I would like to create a wx interface with connectable devices like in the music connection software "catia" or in blender nodes.

Sorry I don't have a code yet. I know how to create a wx panel, but I don't know how to make it moveable by clic and drag. This is the first step of such an interface.

Comment: Check out the AUI widgets in wxPython. I recommend the AGW version of AUI, but I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Mike I'll look that up!

Comment: When you download wxPython a `demo` directory is also included, you could browse through it, I am sure they will have some working examples of this in the demos. You could start from there.

Comment: Thanks for the precision I'll look that too.